# Need to capture and store receiver's details via IPN by using Paypal Mass Pay API

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-nvp

This is a question about Paypal Mass Pay IPN. My platform is **PHP & mySQL**.

All over the Paypal support website, I have found IPN for only payments made. I need an IPN on similar lines for Mass Pay but could not find it. Also tried experimenting with already existing Mass Pay NVP code, but that did not work either.

What I am trying to do is that for all the recipients to whom the payment has been successfully sent via Mass Pay, I want to record their email, amount and unique_id in my own database table. If possible, I want to capture the payment status as well, whether it has been a success of failure and based upon the same, I need to do some in house processing.

**The existing code Mass pay code is below:**

```
<?php

$environment = 'sandbox';   // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'

/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    global $environment;

    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('my_api_username');
    $API_Password = urlencode('my_api_password');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('my_api_signature');

    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment || "beta-sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('51.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}

// Set request-specific fields.
$emailSubject =urlencode('example_email_subject');
$receiverType = urlencode('EmailAddress');
$currency = urlencode('USD');                           // or other currency ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')

// Add request-specific fields to the request string.
$nvpStr="&EMAILSUBJECT=$emailSubject&RECEIVERTYPE=$receiverType&CURRENCYCODE=$currency";

$receiversArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $receiverData = array(  'receiverEmail' => "user$i@paypal.com",
                            'amount' => "example_amount",
                            'uniqueID' => "example_unique_id",
                            'note' => "example_note");
    $receiversArray[$i] = $receiverData;
}

foreach($receiversArray as $i => $receiverData) {
    $receiverEmail = urlencode($receiverData['receiverEmail']);
    $amount = urlencode($receiverData['amount']);
    $uniqueID = urlencode($receiverData['uniqueID']);
    $note = urlencode($receiverData['note']);
    $nvpStr .= "&L_EMAIL$i=$receiverEmail&L_Amt$i=$amount&L_UNIQUEID$i=$uniqueID&L_NOTE$i=$note";
}

// Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
$httpParsedResponseAr = PPHttpPost('MassPay', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) {
    exit('MassPay Completed Successfully: '.print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));


} else  {
    exit('MassPay failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}

?>
```

In the code above, how and where do I add code to capture the fields that I requested above? Any code indicating the solution is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am more familiar with Recurring Payments, but I think the IPN response will send back the values you are seeking. Just capture them out of the array sent back, place them in some variables, and save to the database.

```
$email   = $httpParsedResponseAr["receiver_email"];  
$amount  = $httpParsedResponseAr["mc_currency_x"];
```

Here are the values for the Mass Pay Variables
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_IPNandPDTVariables

Comment: @Christopher: Thank you for the response. I tried out your code but when I checked my DB table for the values, I saw: receiver_email_1 as the email response.  Any ideas on how I can retrieve the values of the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two ways to get this data, one is to look at the responses from the call you make to masspay directly, and the other is setting up IPN for your account.

You have to setup the global IPN, I cannot find a way to send in the IPN listen url as a variable on this call.

HTH
-FT